# How to open context menu with right-click down instead of up?

Tags: firefox, contextmenu, autohotkey

I've been looking, but I can't seem to find how to change the mouse behavior to allow for pressing the right-mouse button down to open the context menu. I would like to be able to press down the right-mouse button to have the menu open, then drag the cursor to a selection and release the right-mouse button, opening the selection. I'm looking to have this behavior only while Firefox is in focus.

Something like:

> If Firefox is in focus
>
> > *Pressing down on the right-mouse button causes a right mouse up event
> >     *Releasing the right-mouse button causes a right mouse click where the cursor is

Is that possible...?

Thank you

Comment: Yes it would be possible, did you try anything?

Comment: Unless you're modifying the Firefox source code, I don't think this question is programming-related.

Comment: I'm not greatly familiar with programming, so I'm hoping this has already been done and someone can link me to the solution so I can apply it to my needs.

Comment: @CodyGray In the context of `autohotkey` it is programing related, unfortunately OP did not post any code, so it is not.

Comment: Correct, I'm not trying to modify the Firefox source code. I want to be able to do as described using AutoHotKey or scripting or whatever so I can make this happen please.

Comment: @BrianPardee And what is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to achieve such. I don't know the coding.

Comment: @BrianPardee Stack Overflow is not a site where you present a problem and we write the code for you.

Comment: What is it for please?

Comment: SO is for fixing non-working achievements or approaches. Since you have neither a solution nor an approach, there's nothing to fix or to suggest improvents for. I always find it cool when beginners try to code something, but no one is a born master. If you don't know anything about programming, you'll have to research, learn and practice before trying to solve something. People don't go to the food bank if they merely don't know how to cook, do they? In this food bank, you'll have to have done your [homework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?) if you expect anyone to help you.

Comment: @MCL +1, what my response would be, if i could articulate it properly.

Comment: `Pressing down on the right-mouse button causes a right mouse up event`: Surely this is a typo?

Comment: Of course, this question belongs to the Superuser or perhaps the UX site, but otherwise it is a *very* valid usability-related question.

Answer (score 1):

The question is pretty old, but the answer is realy simple:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
  *$RButton::
    SendInput, {RButton Up}
  Return
  RButton Up::
    SendInput, {LButton}
  Return
```